# Google Cloud Monitoring Alert when Cloud Function status!=ok, it doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

__

Hello,

I would like to know how to raise a Alert Email notication when my Cloud-Function status is not "ok".

[image]

I have configured my Cloud Monitoring alert as described in image above,
but I do not receive any email notification.

Here if how my threshold is confidured:

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot , "Alert Trigger" is "All timeseries violate" , change it to "Any timeseries violate" it should work.

Also verify notification channel set correctly.

Comment: Hello thank you for your feedback, unfortunately this doesn't worked. 
I can see the metrics on the graphic  but, I don't receive the alert.